# hyperalgebras (positive characteristic)

Tags: characteristic-p, rt.representation-theory

The question is about commutator in integral forms. Let $A$ an associative algebra over a field of characteristic zero, $x\in A$ and $k\in \mathbb Z$, we denote $x^{(k)}=\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$.
How to calculate brackets $[x_\beta^{(n)}, x_\alpha^{(m)}]$? Can I proceed doing the calculation for $[x_\beta^{n}, x_\alpha^{m}]$ and then multiply by $\frac{1}{n!m!}$ and try to rewrite the result in a divided power notation?

ADDED:
Let $g$ be a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra and $\{\alpha_i,...,\alpha_n\}$ the set of positive roots. It is known that there exist an integral form for $U(g)$ and it is generated by $(x_{\alpha}^-)^{(k)}$ where $k>0$ and $\alpha$ is a positive root.

Comment: Please, explain the context/starting point of your calculation. Aren't relations between $x_\alpha^{(n)}$ and $x_\beta^{(m)}$ part of the algebra structure?

Comment: The term "hyperalgebra" usually applies to a different setting than this one, which makes the initial question unclear.   It's helpful to indicate the background sources you are starting with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, your question is about relations on the generators of the Garland integral form for the hyper loop algebra of $\mathfrak g$. Maybe the following papers will help you:

H.Garland, The arithmetic theory of loop algebras, J. Algebra 53 (1978), 480--551.

D. Jakelic, A. Moura, Finite-dimensional representations of hyper loop algebras, Pacific J. Math. 233 (2007), 371--402.